# Bukkit event thrown on creeper destruction or enderman block-taking?

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit

What is the name of the event that gets triggered when a creeper destroys blocks, and how do I use it?

Similarly, when an Enderman steals a block from the world, another event is called, what is it and how is it used?

Comment: I'm sorry this question got closed again. Imo, the question is ___clear___. You're looking for the proper events. The answer is simple. It's far from _"Too broad"_. The downvotes you got on here are ridiculous. Sure, it's not the best question, but come on.

Comment: @Kyll have to tag you again... Idk what is going on with downvotes and votes to close

Comment: @Kerooker: Sadly, we can only reopen-vote a question _once_.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When a Creeper destroys blocks via explosion, the event `EntityExplodeEvent` is called. You can check an example on how to use it below:

```
@EventHandler
public void onCreeperExplode(EntityExplodeEvent e) {
    Entity entity = e.getEntity();
    if (entity.getType().equals(EntityType.CREEPER)) {
    //It's a creeper
    //You can cancel it
    e.setCancelled(true);    //This prevents damage

    //Or cancel the block destruction
    e.blockList().clear();
    }
}
```

---

For the Enderman block-taking, you can use an `EntityBlockChangeEvent`, called whenever an entity changes a block (excluding players).

```
@EventHandler
public void onEndermanBlockTake(EntityChangeBlockEvent e) {
    Entity entity = e.getEntity();
    if (entity.getType().equals(EntityType.Enderman)) {
        //It's an enderman
        Block b = e.getBlock();    //Getting the block
        e.setCancelled(true);    //Cancelling the event
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

[org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityExplodeEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/entity/EntityExplodeEvent.html) for Creeper exploding and [org.bukkit.event.entity.EntityChangeBlockEvent](https://hub.spigotmc.org/javadocs/spigot/org/bukkit/event/entity/EntityChangeBlockEvent.html) for enderman griefing.